# Powershell search CSV against Hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv, hashtable

This seems very basic yet I can't find or figure out anywhere.

I have 2 CVS files, I would like to import one and change an ID column to a relevant string contained in another .csv, then export the results to a file. I've been experimenting with hashtables but cannot seem to figure it out.

Current:

```
Main.csv                                      Reference.csv       
Type_ID    Category_ID     Location_ID        Type_ID     Type 
1          11              111                1           Tablet
2          22              222                2           Laptop
3          33              333                3           Workstation
```

Would like it to read:

```
Type        Category_ID     Location_ID        
Tablet      11              111                
Laptop      22              222               
Workstation 33              333
```

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#import file as hash table
$t = Import-Csv -Path .\Reference.csv -Header  "column1","column2"
$HashTable = @{}
foreach($r in $t)
{
    Write-Host $r.column1 $r.column2
    $HashTable[$r.column1] = $r.column2
}
$HashTable

#compare ID and assign string
 ForEach($_.Type_ID in (Import-CSV .\Main.csv)){
    If($HashTable.ContainsKey($_.column1)){
      $_.column1=$HashTable[$_.column2]
      }
    $_
    } | Export-Csv .\it_works.csv
```

Any advise is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can create a Hashtable :

```
Import-Csv C:\dumy\b.csv | % {$t=@{}}{$t+=@{$_.type_id=$_.type}}
```

Then :

```
Import-Csv C:\dumy\a.csv | select @{name = "Type"; expression={$t[$_.type_id]}},Category_ID,Location_ID  | export-csv 'c:\dumy\c.csv'
```

Comment: Merci monsieur @JPBlanc,
It works just as I asked, may I ask how would I insert a column before Type? My file has many columns (I choose 3 for simplicity) and have no problem adding more to the right using the comma but I seem to be reaching errors when inserting a column before Type. 
Example:
`Import-Csv C:\dumy\a.csv | Category_ID, select @{name = "Type"; expression={$t[$_.type_id]}},Location_ID  | export-csv 'c:\dumy\c.csv'`

Comment: I was moving the select with the @. Solved
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx